# Sql Server encoding issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently i have requested a script to be update to a certain server.

```
UPDATE xtable set xvalue = N'Â?thisisatest'
```

but when i look at the actual result the special character Â is not there. the value I saw is "?thisisatest"

I don't have the access to this server. When I tried the script on my local machine it is working as my expectation.

The datatype value of xvalue column is nvarchar(max)

any thoughts

Comment: The datatype is nvarchar(max) thats why i have put N''

Comment: `UPDATE xtable set x.value = U&'\00C2?thisisatest'`? ANSI SQL solution, don't know if SQL Server supports it.

Comment: BTW, do you know if it's an insert problem, or a select problem? (Check the length.)

Comment: what is `x` in your statement? What is the value in `[value]` before you update?

Comment: sorry guys remove the x. its only value where value is the column name

Comment: How do you "look" at the result? What does `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Value) FROM xtable` yield? (It should be `0xC2003F0074006800690073006900730061007400650073007400`, the code points of your string in UTF-16).